# Terraform Defining key-value from within for_loop?

Tags: terraform

Example Code

```
resource "null_resource" "send_instance_ips" {
  
  depends_on = [aws_instance.funskies] 
  
  for_each = {
  
    for idx, instance in [aws_instance.funskies]: idx => instance
    
    idx.key = instance.public_ip
    idx.value = instance.private_ip
  }

  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    user = "fun-user"
    private_key = file("~/id_rsa")
    host = each.value.public_ip
  }
  
  provisioner "remote-exec" { 
     inline = [
        "echo 'Hello ${each.value}' > /home/centos/all_ip.txt"
    ]
  }
```

Error that I get

```
Error: Invalid 'for' expression

  on modules.tf line 9, in resource "null_resource" "send_instance_ips":
   5:   for_each = {
   6:
   7:     for idx, instance in [aws_instance.funskies]: idx => instance
   8:
   9:   idx.key = instance.public_ip
```

**Question:** How do modify my `each` the key-value pair to include specific elements of my `instance`

Comment: That looks like it would work "as-is" if you removed the extraneous invalid syntax part of the for expression: `idx.key = instance.public_ip idx.value = instance.private_ip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `null_resource` should be in the following form if you want to use `key` and `value`:

```
resource "null_resource" "send_instance_ips" {
  
  for_each = { for idx, instance in [aws_instance.funskies]:
               idx=> {key  = instance.public_ip
                      value = instance.private_ip}
             }
  
  connection {
   type = "ssh"
    user = "fun-user"
    private_key = file("~/id_rsa")
    host = each.value.key
  }  
  
  provisioner "remote-exec" { 
      inline = [
        "echo 'Hello ${each.value.value}' > /home/centos/all_ip.txt"
     ]
  }     
}
```

But since you have only one `aws_instance` you really don't need `for_each` in this example.

By the way, if you want to eliminate `idx` and do something like:

```
{ for idx, instance in [aws_instance.funskies]:
         instance.public_ip => instance.private_ip
}
```

it will not work, as public_ip is not known before hand.